# low framerate when running iframeextractor on iphone device

Tags: iphone, ios, ipad

Would like to ask if anyone has encounter low framerate when running iframeextractor on iphone device. When i running it on simulator the video is fine but when code is run on iphone device, the framerate became slow. Do anyone know whats the cause? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

The iphone processor is much slower than your desktop mac, and has less resources. rgb image conversion is slow.